# Using ES6 dependency in script JS tag of a HTML file

Tags: javascript, import, es6-modules

I am trying to load the `uuid` module, which is a project dependency, inside a .html file in a project managed by webpack,

```
<script type="module">
      import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";
      window.uuidv4 = uuidv4;

      console.log('uuidv4 ', uuidv4);
 </script>
```

But this is failing with an error `(index):1 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "uuid". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`

If I try to reference a specific `js` file relative to the html file, it works properly

```
<script type="module">
      import myFunc from "./functions/myFunc.js";
      window.uuidv4 = uuidv4;

      console.log('uuidv4 ', uuidv4);
 </script>
```

Why can't I call the dependency directly in the html, although if I load it directly from myFunc.js it works?

**myFunc.js**

```
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";
console.log('uuidv4 ', uuidv4); // this works here

export default myFunc() {
   console.log('Hello!');
}
```

Comment: You'll need to search for solutions to import "bare modules" in HTML files. I'll try to answer when i reach a laptop. Also are you using a bundler right now?

Comment: Yes I am using webpack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason `import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";` works inside `myFunc.js` is because it's being bundled by Webpack, and Webpack knows how to resolve modules without `"/", "./", or "../"` during the bundle time. Eventually all these modules will be in the same file `bundle.js` (if you haven't customized it).

When you're using the import directly in HTML, the JS code is run directly inside the browser. So the browser doesn't understand how to interpret it. Check out this explanation for more: https://javascript.info/modules-intro#no-bare-modules-allowed